# "Hello world" tutorial error

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm following [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/) and ran into the following error:

```
> Jul 19, 2013 2:18:14 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
> [/Spring3MVC/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I can open the first `jsp` file (`index.jsp`), but when I click on "say hello" it shows 404 to me. I tried the methods suggested in the comments of the tutorial, but they didn't work.

The only place where I deviated from the tutorial is that I use Tomcat 7 instead of 6. Everything else looks the same using Eclipse. My code is the same as in tutorial, so no need to paste it here right now. :)

the hello.jsp file path is:

```
Spring3MVC\WebContent\WEB-INF\jsp\hello.jsp
```

web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans


http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Tomcatlog:

```
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Python27;C:\cloudbees-sdk-1.5.0;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\eclipse\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools;C:\tomcat 7.0.12;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;.
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3MVC' did not find a matching property.
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 834 ms
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 19 15:25:02 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@44dc42ab: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 628 ms
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1982 ms
Jul 19, 2013 3:25:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring3MVC/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
Jul 19, 2013 3:35:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring3MVC/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

(PS! maybe you can point me to a working tutorial as well)

Comment: change it `@RequestMapping("/hello")` to `@RequestMapping("/hello.html")` from contoller.

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: can you post your added code?

Comment: `@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
 
    @RequestMapping("/hello.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
 
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}`

Comment: Update your question by adding your code from configuration xml file, and location of your jsp file.

Comment: not completely sure what you meant by configuration files, but i pasted my -servlet.xml and web.xml file content to the post =)

Comment: can you please post the tomcat log that you see when you start it?

Answer (score 2):

Your file is named `sprint-servlet.xml`? Maybe that's the problem.

As Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out, it's supposed to be named after the  tag, by default.

The name of the file should be `spring-servlet.xml`.

An example of a spring application is [here](https://code.google.com/p/dispora-java/source/browse/trunk/mavenized/).

An official Spring tutorial is [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/).

Comment: It's supposed to be named after the `<servlet-name>` tag, by default.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis look at the question. The asker has written "sprint-servlet.xml file:"

Comment: its spring-servlet.xml.. typo, fixed now :)

Comment: @MihkelL. I added some links to a working Maven Spring project and to the official Spring MVC tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Several good, simple working Spring-MVC tutorials are here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

(See the links at the bottom of the page...)